# Insert Multiple Data using a Checkbox in Datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I want to insert multiple data to Excel consider by checking a `CheckBox` in a `DataGridView`. I have done like this but it still gives an error. It says:

> Query input must contain at least one table or query.

Actually, the table in Excel is correct but the error still always shows. Can anyone help me?

```
string konekpengisian2 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\Data Pengisian SLA Surabaya\\" + new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("id-ID").DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek) + "_" + System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("id-ID")) + ".xlsx" + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=NO;'";

private void MoveToScheduleBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in ReviewGV.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells[0].Value) == true) //Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells[0].Value) == true
        {
            //try
            //{
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Apakah Anda yakin memasukkan WSID tersbeut ke Jadwal Pengisian ?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(konekpengisian2);
                OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();
                kon.Open();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Schedule$] ([WSID], [Lokasi], [Cass A Den 50], [Cass B Den 50], [Cass C Den 100], [Cass D Den 100], [Reject], [Saldo]) VALUES (wsid, lokasi, cassa, cassb, cassc, casdd, reject, saldo) WHERE [WSID] = '" + item.Cells[1].Value + "'";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("wsid", item.Cells[1].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lokasi", item.Cells[2].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("cassa", item.Cells[3].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("cassb", item.Cells[4].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("cassc", item.Cells[5].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("cassd", item.Cells[6].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("reject", item.Cells[7].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("saldo", item.Cells[8].Value);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                kon.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil dipindah ke Jadwal Pengisian !");
            }
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            { 
                //do nothing
            }                    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
"INSERT INTO [Schedule$] ([WSID], [Lokasi], [Cass A Den 50], [Cass B Den 50], [Cass C Den 100], [Cass D Den 100], [Reject], [Saldo]) VALUES (wsid, lokasi, cassa, cassb, cassc, casdd, reject, saldo)
```

no need for where clause if you aren't updating.

Comment: If I don't use WHERE, it even can not read my excel header. Can you help me ?

Comment: If I don't use WHERE, it even can not read my excel header. Can you help me ? It says 'The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'WSID'.  Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.'

Comment: are you sure you have WSID field in your excel? since it can't recognize field name it might have different name or it might be identity column and in that case you don't even need to insert wsid field. can you provide your excel sheet struct?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I tried to delete WSID from my code. My code even can not read [Lokasi]. When I deleted [Lokasi], it can not read [Cass A Den 50]